# Is it stupid to do l2 normalization with sklearns Normalizer for a correlation analysis on this type of dataset?

Tags: scikit-learn, correlation, normalization, cheminformatics

## My Data:

I have a dataset of molecules, their activities and physicochemical descriptors. Each row corresponds to a molecule and each column to a descriptor. There are 80 molecules with 10 descriptors. Some descriptor values are positive and negative and the scales vary strongly. There are also some outliers.

## Preprocessing step:

I normalized this dataset with `sklearn`'s `Normalizer`, with the defaults, by using

```
norm = Normalizer()
descriptors_norm = pd.DataFrame(norm.fit_transform(new_df), columns=new_df.columns)
```

## Analysis:

I calculated a correlation matrix and saw some interesting relationships between descriptors and activities.

```
corr_matrix = descriptors_norm.corr()
ax = sns.heatmap(corr_matrix, cmap = "Spectral");
```

## The problem:

If I plot the original unnormalized values against each other, I can't see any correlation in some cases. They only appear for the normalized values.
I found that the most dominant correlations were still there (e.g. between molecular weight and the number of valence electrons), but new, interesting ones between activities and physicochemical descriptors popped up.

Is the use of this `Normalizer` valid for my case, e.g. it helped to find complex relationships, or did I just destroy my data?

## What I tried:

I tried the correlation analysis with different preprocessing methods (`MinMaxScaler` and `StandardScaler`). The new correlations could not be observed (only weak correlation coefficients around 0.3, while they were around 0.6 for the `Normalizer`). I would have expected that these methods also might show these correlations, if they are really in my data.

I also tried the `Normalizer(norm = "l1")` and it also found these correlations, like for the default `Normalizer`.

I tried to work with unnormalized data and used different correlation coefficients for the correlation matrix (Spearman, Kendall) and did not find these correlations. If the relationships are nonlinear, they should have popped up, right?